# JAVA - Passing a generic enum as a method parameter for a constructor

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have three different types of enums (itemsA, itemsB and itemsC) and a Class "Product". So far, I'm passing one enum as a parameter for my product constructor, having three constructors:

```
static Product actualProduct;
        
public static void setActualProduct(itemsA currentProduct) {
                actualProduct = new Product(currentProduct);
        
public static void setActualProduct(itemsB currentProduct) {
                actualProduct = new Product(currentProduct);
        
public static void setActualProduct(itemsC currentProduct) {
                actualProduct = new Product(currentProduct);
```

*class Product*

```
public class Product {
    private String productId;
    private String name;

    public Product(itemsA item) {
            this.productId = item.getId();
            this.name = item.getProductName();
     }
    
    public Product(itemsB item) {
            this.productId = item.getId();
            this.name = item.getProductName();
            this.category = item.getCategory();
    }
    
    public Product(itemsC item) {
            this.productId = item.getId();
            this.name = item.getProductName();
    }
```

*enum example: itemsA*

```
public enum itemsA{

    item1("00001", "itemName", BuySections.TOYS);

    private final String id;
    private final String productName;
    private final BuySections section;

    item1(String id, String name, BuySections section){
        this.id = id;
        this.productName = name;
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getProductName(){
        return productName;
    }
```

So, I think should be a way to implement this using some generics. Something like this:

```
public static void setActualProduct(Enum<?> itemType) {
            actualProduct = new Product<?>(itemType);
```

Any help would be very apreciated.

Comment: It looks to me as though you can just make your enums implement an interface which contains getId, getProductName, and getCategory. Then you can create a product from any instance which implements that interface.

Comment: You are doing different operation for different enum parameter in constructor how it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let your enums implement a common interface:

```
interface CommonInterface {
    public String getId();
    public String getProductName();
    public BuySection getBuySection();
}
enum FstEnum implements CommonInterface {}
enum SndEnum implements CommonInterface {}

class Product<E extends Enum<E> & CommonInterface> {
    E type;
    Product(E type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public static <E extends Enum<E> & CommonInterface> void setActualProduct(E itemType) {
        actualProduct = new Product<E>(itemType);
}
```

A few remarks wrt. naming conventions: class names should be singular (`BuySection`, not `BuySections`), enums should begin with uppercase letters (as should all types, e.g. `ItemsA`, not `itemsA`)

Comment: As long as we're being *that way* about naming, wouldn't a name in the language of the *business domain* be a better choice than a name in the *programming language domain*? I vote for *Item*.

Comment: ...Ditto for *`FstEnum`* and *`SndEnum`*.

Comment: @deduper If I knew the business domain i would have chosen descriptive type names. But I have no Idea what `itemsA` should be and I don`t wager a guess. I absolutely agree that the names I have chosen have no place in production code, but I also have no clue as to what OPs classes should represent in the first place.

Comment: Going by the example code in the original post, my guess is the OP is working in a domain where you can *Buy* different *Products*. Evidently the *Products* you can *Buy* in the OP's *shop* are *sectionalized* into different *Items*. I don't now what the OP's *actual* business domain is IRL any more than you. But, the names he originally used are pretty good clues for better names for new or replacement types introduced into his system. I vote for *Item*.

Comment: @deduper I am perfectly fine with not tying my example to a specific business domain. Sure, in OPs case that might be appropriate, but lets not forget OP might not be the only one with a similar problem. Type names are completely interchangeable anyways, its the mechanism that is important.

Comment: @deduper Btw, your guess might be wrong, because OP calls the constructor parameter `itemType`, indicating that its not actually an item they are modelling, but some kind of classifier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. you can make `enum` implements a common `interface` and create a constructor using the `interface`. following is the example

```
interface GenericEnum{}

enum Item1 implements GenericEnum {
   TOYS1;
}

enum Item2 implements GenericEnum {
   TOYS2;
}


class Test {
  public GenericEnum genericEnum;

  public Test(GenericEnum genericEnum) {
     this.genericEnum = genericEnum;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you define different enums containing just single values, instead of defining one single enum containing different values. Something like this:

```
public enum Item {

    item1("00001", "itemName", BuySections.TOYS),
    item2("00002", "itemName2", BuySections.TOYS),
    item3("00003", "itemName3", BuySections.TOYS);

    private final String id;
    private final String productName;
    private final BuySections section;

    Item(String id, String name, BuySections section){
        this.id = id;
        this.productName = name;
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getProductName(){
        return productName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you plan on answering the main point of his question: „*Passing a generic enum as a method parameter for a constructor*“?

Comment: Hi, we did it like this because we have hundres of differents products all group by types, each types with its own properties.

Comment: OK. But this way you have no benefit of using an enum. The way you use it, it only makes your life harder IMHO. If i understand it correctly, the type is more like a DTO of product properties. So you could just define an interface for that, no need for an enum.

Sorry if i don't just answer your question directly, but i am not certain if it is the right solution for your problem.